# Unable to write streaming multiple records in Cosmos db

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I am able to write the data in Cosmos DB being sent to Eventhub by the [TelcoGenerator app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-real-time-fraud-detection#start-the-event-generator-application). But it's getting one record(after refresh) in the cosmos at one time. Here is the code snippet

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()


def write2Cosmos (df2, batchid):
    df2.withColumn("batchId",current_timestamp())\
        .write.format("cosmos.oltp").option("spark.synapse.linkedService", "<LinkedServiceName>")\
        .option("spark.cosmos.container", "<DatabaseName>")\
        .mode('append')\
        .save()


df = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))

from pyspark.sql.functions import json_tuple
df=df.select(json_tuple(col("body"),"RecordType","SwitchNum")) \
    .toDF("id","SwitchNum")

streamQuery = df\
    .writeStream\
    .foreachBatch(write2Cosmos) \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/temp")\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .start()
streamQuery.awaitTermination()
```

Any pointers to load the whole data(Till the streaming runs)?

Screengrab for input data
[image]

Screengrab for Cosmos data with only one record
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the partition column which has multiple values. Try changing to the `SwitchNum` column as below:

```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import json_tuple
  df=df.select(json_tuple(col("body"),"RecordType","SwitchNum")) \
    .toDF("RecordType","id")
```